# How to use a logger in c# class stored in Shared folder

Tags: c#, azure, logging, azure-functions

I am using C# class in Shared folder in Azure function. I want to print and see the log statements. How can I see the logs?

Azure function

```
#load "..\Shared\Message.csx"

using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

public static void Run(TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed message: {message.Id}");
     Message(log);

}
```

C# Class in Shared folder

```
public class Message(TraceWriter log) {
  log.Info("Testing messages");

}
```

I don't see "Testing messages" printed when I run the Azure function.

Comment: Where do you call that Message function?

Comment: @GolezTrol I call Message() from Azure function. I have updated the question.

Comment: I always wonder, why do you have to add that line to the question. If it was missing from your question, wasn't it also missing from your original code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you copy-pasted incorrectly, the problem is that `Message` definition is invalid C# code. You should do something like

```
public class Message
{
    public static void Info(TraceWriter log) 
    {
        log.Info("Testing messages");
    }
}
```

and then call

```
Message.Info(log);
```

On a side note, I advise you to move to precompiled functions that you can create in Visual Studio 15.3, where you won't have to deal with script files and compiler errors will be more visible.